# Create lists for all nested lists, all nested list lengths

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list like:

```
list = {{3, 1, 4}, {1, 5}, {9, 2, 6}, {5, 3}, {5, 8, 9, 7}, {9, 3},
       {2}, {3, 8, 4, 6, 2, 6}, {4, 3, 3}, {8}, {3, 2, 7, 9, 5, 0}}
```

Now I can select all nested lists of length 6:

```
Select[list, Length[#] == 6 &]
```

which gives the following result:

```
{{3, 8, 4, 6, 2, 6}, {3, 2, 7, 9, 5, 0}}
```

Now I want to create lists like this for lengths 1, 2, ... maximum length. I understand I'll need

```
Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Length /@ list]]
```

which gives

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 6}
```

How do I run over this list with the `Select` function above?

Comment: Does `GatherBy[list,Length]` do what you want?

Comment: @n.j.evans - More or less. I want each of the sublists as separate lists, but I think I can handle that. Thanks.

Comment: `Table[Set[x[Last@Dimensions@i], i], {i, GatherBy[list, Length]}]` will gather the lists then set them to the values of `x[len]`, where `x[1]` is the length 1 lists, and `x[2]` all the length 2 lists etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) as [N.J.Evans](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11777/n-j-evans) suggested:

```
list = {{3, 1, 4}, {1, 5}, {9, 2, 6}, {5, 3}, {5, 8, 9, 7}, {9, 3}, {2}, {3, 8, 4, 
    6, 2, 6}, {4, 3, 3}, {8}, {3, 2, 7, 9, 5, 0}};

GatherBy[Sort @ list, Length]
```

> ```
> {{{2}, {8}},
>  {{1, 5}, {5, 3}, {9, 3}},
>  {{3, 1, 4}, {4, 3, 3}, {9, 2, 6}},
>  {{5, 8, 9, 7}},
>  {{3, 2, 7, 9, 5, 0}, {3, 8, 4, 6, 2, 6}}}
> ```

Or with [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) for explicit length values:

```
KeySort @ GroupBy[list, Length]
```

> ```
> <|1 -> {{2}, {8}},
>   2 -> {{1, 5}, {5, 3}, {9, 3}}, 
>   3 -> {{3, 1, 4}, {9, 2, 6}, {4, 3, 3}},
>   4 -> {{5, 8, 9, 7}}, 
>   6 -> {{3, 8, 4, 6, 2, 6}, {3, 2, 7, 9, 5, 0}}|>
> ```

Comment: Or `SplitBy[Sort @ list, Length]`

Comment: @corey979 Yes, but oddly `SplitBy` usually seems to be slower than `GatherBy` so I tend to default to the latter.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is important, you can use `Sow` and `Reap` to define two functions: `ListsofLength` and `Lengths`. I define them as such:

```
ListsOfLength[list_, length_] := 
  If[ListQ[#], #, {}] &@(length /. Lengths[list]);
Lengths[list_] := Lengths[list] = Last@Reap[Sow[#, Length[#]] & /@ list;, _, Rule];
```

Here you call `ListOfLengths` with your list and the desired lengths as input. It calls `Lengths` which is the expensive function that uses `Sow` and tags all sublists with their respective lengths. `Reap` can then extract the sublists, grouping together the different tags (=lengths) and supplying them as a rule for easy use.
Since `Lengths` is memoized it's only expensive the first time you call `ListOfLengths`.

For long lists it's about four times faster, see:

```
list = Table[RandomInteger[{0, 10}, RandomInteger[{1, 5}]], 1000000];
GatherBy[Sort@list, Length][[2]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*returns 3.16s*)
ListsOfLength[list, 2]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*returns 0.81s*)
```

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't understand the point of this.  This only returns a single length rather than all lengths as the OP requested.  For a single length of two with your example data `Select[list, Length@# == 2 &]` is faster than `ListsOfLength[list, 2]`, and `Pick[list, Length /@ list, 2]` is faster still.

Comment: I imagined a usecase where Op wants to access some list of sublists individually which he can by using `ListsOfLength`. So if at one point he's wants all lists of length '5' he calculates the expensive function `Lengths[list]` (which is a faster version of your `GroupBy` answer) once and if later he wants lists of length 10 it'll basically be free.
Ultimately `ListsOfLength` is just a fancy wrapper.
If that doesn't make sense feel free to downvote and I might delete the answer if it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Function`:

```
Function[{x}, Select[list, Length[#] == x &]] /@ 
 Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Length /@ list]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to illustrate `GroupBy` and `Reap`/`Sow`:

```
gb = GroupBy[list, Length]
sw = Last@Reap[Sow[#, Length@#] & /@ list, _, Rule]
fg[n_?(MemberQ[Keys[gb], #] &)] := n /. gb
fg[n_] := "Missing"
fs[n_?(MemberQ[Keys[sw], #] &)] := n /. gb
fs[n_] := "Missing"
```

So,

```
With[{rg = Range[6]}, 
 Grid[Transpose[{rg, fg /@ rg, fs /@ rg}], Frame -> All]]
```

[image]